# The dimension of a closed set of $\mathbb{C}P^n\times\mathbb{C}P^n\times \mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb{C}P^n\times\mathbb{C}P^n\times \mathbb{C}P^n$ be the set of points $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\}$  s.t. some $x_i=x_j$, then why is the codimension of $X$ $n$?

Now $X=Z(x_1=x_2)\cup Z(x_3=x_2)\cup Z(x_1=x_3)$ and each union component has codimension $n$. Why is $X$ also with codimension $n$?

Comment: Consider writing it as the union of multiple varieties you can express easily. What varieties can you write it as a union of in a simple case, like $n=1$ or $n=2$?

Comment: @KReiser it's the union of $x_1=x_2$, $x_1=x_3$, $x_2=x_3$, each of them has codimension $1$, then why is the union still with codimension $1$?

Comment: @KReiser I mean $n=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is confusion that the $x_i$ are like coordinates? But they are not, each $x_i$ is rather a line which itself has $n+1$ homogeneous coordinates.

So, lets change notation from $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to $(x,y,z)$. Then $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb CP^n\times\mathbb C P^n \times \mathbb C P^n$, and each variable can be written in homogeneous coordinates like so: $$x = [x_0:\cdots:x_n]$$
$$y = [y_0:\cdots:y_n]$$
$$z = [z_0:\cdots:z_n]$$

Setting for example $x = y$ means that $[x_0:\cdots:x_n] = [y_0:\cdots:y_n]$. When $x_0 = y_0 = 1$, this leaves us with $n$ separate equations to impose, $x_1=y_1,x_2=y_2,\ldots x_n=y_n$. Therefore $Z(x=y)$ is of codimension $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I feel confused. I agree $Z(x=y)$ is of codimension $n$, my question is why $Z(x=y)\cup Z(z=y)\cup Z(z=x)$ has codimension $n$?

Comment: The dimension of $X$ is by definition the maximum of the dimension of its components, in this case they are all the same. So the codimension is the same as any of its components too.